# 'Inverted' Zeta Function, swapping zeroes and primes

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

What is known about a kind of dual version of the Riemann zeta function defined $\bar{\zeta}(n)$ as follows:

If there is a duality between the primes and non-trivial Riemann zeta-zeroes. We can convert
$$
\zeta(s) = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}
$$
for prime $p$, into a new function
$$
\bar{\zeta}(n)=\prod_{\rho}\frac{1}{1-n^{-\rho}}
$$
where the product is now over non-trivial zeroes. By plotting this for a finite number of zeroes it appears that the new function goes to zero at the primes, i.e. the primes are the new zeros.

There is a note describing this [here](https://www.authorea.com/users/5445/articles/117672-flipping-the-zeta-function?mode=edit).

[image: Plot]

Question 2: Is there a consistent duality of the natural numbers. I.e. simplistically speaking if
$$
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}
$$
can we find an expression
$$
\bar{\zeta}(n)= \sum_{\gamma} \frac{1}{n^\gamma}
$$
for some set of $\gamma$, that represent the natural numbers in the 'zeroes' sense? They might be complex numbers for example, or of the form $\gamma = \rho_1^{k_1} \rho_2^{k_2} \cdots$, i.e. in analogy to integers and products of primes.

Comment: Your product doesn't converge, but $1-\sum_\rho x^{\rho-1}$ converges in the sense of distributions, to $\sum_{p^k} \delta(x-p^k) \log p$, this is the Riemann explicit formula.

Comment: *Obiouvsly* I meant $(1-\sum_\rho x^{\rho-1})1_{x>1}$